# How do I implement thread affinity in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

I am using a third-party API which requires thread affinity i.e. The third-party API returns a handle which any subsequent third-party API calls using that handle must execute on the same exact thread. What's is the best way to implement this in standard C++11 (using no other 3rd party libraries e.g. boost etc.)?

Ideally, I would like to be able to pass in closures of the form

```
[&] { return api_function(_handle, parameters); }
```

to a thread that the handle is created on if at all possible.

My initial inclination is to create a std::thread which executes tasks that are added to a std::queue. Is this the best solution?

Comment: Thread affinity is not something the standard library's threading functionalities recognizes.

Comment: What you describe is not what I understand as *"thread affinity"*. It sounds like you need the ability to run specific threads and to *dispatch* instructions (and data) to each one of those threads on demand. That sounds a little broad for `SO` to be honest.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Are you implying that it cannot be done? As it seems creating a worker thread that loops on a (sychronized) queue's contents (of type <std::function<short()>), and then acts on its contents seems doable.

Comment: @Galik Yes, there seems to be confusion over that and what I would call processor affinity i.e. pinning a thread or process to a particular core. Is that what you think of as thread affinity?

Comment: @markf78 You can absolutely do that, but I don't see what that has to do with thread affinity?

Comment: That sounds like you just need to take care not to call that lib's code from anywhere else, so the first step is to /not/ break the rule. The second step is then to implement a task queue that this thread serves and which can be used from anywhere to execute code using that library. Check out `std::function` to hold the tasks, the rest is just work and/or finding the right tool in the standard library or elsewhere.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I was about to edit my question to say this was the direction I was leaning but before I go and implement I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing either a) better solution b) a potential setback that I would be overlooking.

Comment: As far as *design patterns* go I would think *producer consumer* would be worth looking at for feeding specific request data to specific consumer threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any subsequent third-party API calls using that handle must execute on
>   the same exact thread

This is not [*affinity (in the context of processing)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) -- which is the binding of a thread, or an entire process, to a particular CPU/core. What you require is to make sure **no other thread runs your tasks** -- **no matter on which processing unit** the thread runs or whether it keeps running on the same unit or switches to another.

> My initial inclination is to create a std::thread which executes tasks
>   that are added to a std::queue. Is this the best solution?

Well this could definitely work for you. You'll be pushing tasks from any thread to, let's say a `std::queue<std::function<RetValType()>>` (just make sure to synchronize access), and calling `pop()` on it one at a time from your singular thread that is allowed to do so.

This works in accordance with your request to be pushing these sort of expressions:

```
[&] { return api_function(_handle, parameters); }
```

into the queue.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the first paragraph which I consider ambiguous in order that I can mark this as an answer. Wikipedia defines processor affinity to be what you call thread affinity which is how I always understood this.

Comment: Dear @markf78, I think I see your point about the potential confusion when referring to both _process_ and _processor_ while explaining *processor affinity*. I do think part of the contribution thanks to your question is exactly the distinction between what is meant by _affinty_ and by what was meant by you in the question, as I'm sure you're not the only one. As the idea of this site is to be clarifying such matters for future readers, I left the short paragraph -- but hopefully thanks to you made the explanation clearer. Let me know if you still find it problematic.